# is there way to run magento 2 without mcrypt

Tags: magento2, mcrypt

I have a server they don't allow to install mcrypt also.
my magento 2 version not running without it.
**is there way to fix this.or up and running without mcrypt**

Answer (score 1):

Can you please let me know about exact subversion of Magento2 are you using?

If you are using latest version then mcrypt has been already removed since Magento 2.3 release. For more details you may visit devdocs https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html. Mcrypt has been also deprecated from php version 7.2.

Please let me know your magento and php exact version.

Happy to help!

Thanks,